# How to get variable from function in class?

Tags: python

I have this code:

```py
class Character():
    def Armor():
        name = 'Leather armor'
        hp = 10

    def Helmet():
        name = 'Leather helmet'
        hp = 5

    def Sword():
        name = 'Wooden sword'
        dps = 5

    def Name():
        None
```

And I need to call variables from this class like this:
`print('You have: Leather armor with hp 10, Leather helmet with hp 5')` and etc
How to do this?

Comment: Why are using functions for these. You can make them a global Attribute.

Comment: And even if you want them as a method, you can write `print('You have....')` inside the method, so when you call the method, it gets printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fetch the values of the variables from the class, you can either modify the methods to return you the required values and use it as per your convenience as below:-

##### Code

```
class Character():
    def Armor():
        name = 'Leather armor'
        hp = 10
        return name+" with "+hp

    def Helmet():
        name = 'Leather helmet'
        hp = 5
        return name+" with "+hp

    def Sword():
        name = 'Wooden sword'
        dps = 5
        return name+" with "+dps

    def Name():
        None

# Creating Character class instance and printing the values

c = Character()
print("You have: "+c.Armor() + " "+c.Helmet())

# This will print: - 'You have: Leather armor with hp 10, Leather helmet with hp 5'
```

##### Suggestion: -

> Renaming your function in the above case from `Armor()` -> `getArmor()` and `Helmet()` -> `getHelmet()`
>
> This clarifies the use case of the above functions

Comment: How does this print “with” ?

Answer (score -1):

It is not necessary to have methods to create variables that you just want to access. You should either create class variables for the names and hp of each armor piece. Or, the preferred method, create a class for the objects in the character's inventory. For example:

```
class Character():
    def __init__(self, name):  
        self.name = name
        self.inventory = []

    def getName(this):
        return this.name

class Item():
    def __init__(self, name, hp):  
        self.name = name
        self.hp = hp
    
    def getName(this):
        return this.name

    def getHp(this):
        return this.hp

charlie = Character("charlie")

charlie.inventory.append(Item('Leather armor', 10))
charlie.inventory.append(Item('Leather helmet', 5))
charlie.inventory.append(Item('Wooden sword', 5))


print('You have:')
for x in charlie.inventory:
    print(x.getName(),'with hp',x.getHp())

#OUTPUT:
#You have:
#Leather armor with hp 10
#Leather helmet with hp 5
#Wooden sword with hp 5
```

Comment: don't write pointless getters in Python